# How to parse JWT token from request [Next-Auth]

Tags: reactjs, api, jwt, next.js, next-auth

how can I parse **next-AUTH** JWT session token from upcoming request.

i want to extract the JWT token from another server so i can verify it there.

i am using nextJs with next-AUTH

Answer (score 0):

short answer you can parse it like this:

```
const getRawJwt = (req) => {
    try {
        if (!req.headers.cookie) {
            console.log("no cookie");
            return null
        } else {
            const rawCookieString = req.headers.cookie // raw cookie string, possibly multiple cookies
            const rawCookiesArr = rawCookieString.split(';')

            for (let i = 0; i < rawCookiesArr.length; i++) {
                let cookieArr = rawCookiesArr[i].trim().split('=')[0]
                if (cookieArr.includes("next-auth.session-token")) {
                    return rawCookiesArr[i].trim().split('=')[1]
                }
            }
            return null
        }
    } catch (err) {
        return null
    }
}
```